# Make a button "public" in xaml and c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin

I am building a mobile app using the Xamarin platform. In the solution, there is a `core` project and then the platform specific projects, in this case, `.ios` and `.android`. In my core project I have a XAML layout, with a button element.
My_App.Core.HomePage.xaml

```
<Button x:Name="LoginIcon"
        Image="key.png"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
```

I have some platform specific logic in those projects, the result of this I would like to alter the source of these buttons. e.g.

My_App.ios.customfile.cs:

```
My_App.HomePage.LoginIcon.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("bluetoothg.png");
```

of course, as the button is defined in XAML, `LoginIcon` isn't visible from this file, how can I make this XAML element `public`, so I can reference it from other projects in the solution which reference the core files?

Comment: I'm no expert in XAML, but I believe an MVVM approach would provide the functionality. I don't remember quite how it works, but it abstracts the functionality of the control from the actual logic, allowing for extensibility.

Comment: You are doing something wrong if you are trying to access to GUI control in a MV* pattern

Comment: Isn't the whole point of an MV style to access GUI controls via an abstracted, extensible model?

Answer (score 3):

The [x:FieldModifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/field-modifiers) namespace attribute specifies the access level for generated fields for named XAML elements.

Answer (score 1):

Create a property on your page and return the button:

```
public Button PubLoginIcon{ get{ return LoginIcon; } }
```

BUT, I must say something is wrongly designed if you must access the controls on another page, a better approach is to have the functionality in the page as a public function, in this case you have no need to access the controls.

Comment: The reason, is that all UI stuff is defined in the core project. Bluetooth is dealt with in platform specific code. I want to change a picture to show when a device is connected vs. not. Hence needing to change UI element from platform code. is there another way to do that?

Comment: Yes, just make a public boolean property named Connected, in the set store the boolean and if it's true set the connected image else set the unconnected image, this way you also have a nice property which you can use to check which state is shown (just return the boolean on the get)